# Godot Export Android Not Installing Without any Errors

Tags: android, godot

Android export one click deploy was as simple as it was, until i migrate from Godot 3.2.2 to Godot 3.3. The application was not even installed inside my android device, no errors, no anything.

All the android build requirement are the same between both version of Godot engine i used. Besides, I have used `adb logcat adb logcat godot:V *:S` to check on the error messages, but still have no luck as it shows nothing from the console.

Currently I am using back 3.2.2 to all the build task, but still very keen to solve this android export issues I faced in Godot 3.3.

Anyone please help.

*Update

I managed to get an error message saying:
`Package org.godotengine.test has no certificates at entry res/layout/notification_action.xml; ignoring!`

What should I do now in order for one click deploy to works? I have tried reinstall the engine.

Comment: Did you configure Android Sdk Path on Editor settings? *I'd suppose you did, because it is a rather clear error otherwise, however it is the only thing that comes to mind.*

Comment: @Theraot Yes, i have tried to copy paste all the path from the previous version engine, to the new 3.3 Godot Engine. Anyway, thanks for the help :)